# AngularJS and coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, angularjs

I've created a small calculator and now with help have got it working the way I want in Javascript. When I try and convert this AngularJS to coffeescript I get this error:

Error: Argument 'CalcCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

The code is actually working but the error is showing up in the java console, is there a way to fix this?

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YUza7/13/

Comment: You can include your extra CSS and JS in the *Manage Resources* panel so you don't need your "ugly hack": http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YUza7/12/

Comment: Thank you that is much cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove the ng-app attribute since you use the manual bootstrap:

http://jsfiddle.net/g/YUza7/18/

anyway, you must use manual bootstrap with coffeescript on JsFiddle (the automatic was throwing the error because the coffeescript is not yet executed at that point)

EDIT: fixed the html: http://jsfiddle.net/g/YUza7/19/

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
TodoCtrl = ($scope) ->
    $scope.$watch 'one * two', (value) ->
        $scope.total = value
```

Unfortunately jsFiddle incorrect work with CoffeScript + AngularJS